# Ignore break line with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace, line-breaks

The code below will replace certain text. Actually I get the `$str` data from a text file with `file_get_contents` so please imagine there's a new line in the `$str`.

```
$str = 'From: My Name <myemail@myname.com>
        To: storm@yahoo.com
        Message-ID: <1638618225.203837.1426581391642.JavaMail.yahoo@mail.yahoo.com>';

$old = array("My Name", "To: storm@yahoo.com");
$new   = array("New Name", "");
echo str_replace($old, $new, $str );
```

Output:

```
From: New Name 

Message-ID: <1638618225.203837.1426581391642.JavaMail.yahoo@mail.yahoo.com>
```

Unfortunately after removing `To: storm@yahoo.com`, the code will create a line break. How can I use `str_replace` without creating new break line?

Comment: It doesn't create a line break, it's already there.. And you just replace some text with no text, so the break is still there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said you get this from a text file and if what you show is what is in the text file then it is not creating a newline character, it is actually you that is not removing the already existing new line.

Try

```
$str = 'From: My Name <myemail@myname.com>
        To: storm@yahoo.com
        Message-ID: <1638618225.203837.1426581391642.JavaMail.yahoo@mail.yahoo.com>';

$old = array("My Name", "To: storm@yahoo.com\n");
$new = array("New Name", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't create a new line, it's just left from your [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

So if you want to remove every line which only contains new line characters you can use this:

(Here I first replace the `$old` with the `$new`, after this I [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by new line characters. Then I use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) combined with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove these characters (`["", "\t", "\n", "\r", "\0", "\x0B"]`) from every line. Then I remove all remaining empty lines with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and at the end I [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the string again)

```
echo $str = implode(PHP_EOL,
                array_filter(
                    array_map("trim",
                        explode(PHP_EOL, str_replace($old, $new, $str))
                    )
                )
            );
```

Comment: You beauty bro, I was looking for a solution to write to a .htaccess file, and this worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` does not add a new line break; it replaces the string with what you supported and you told it to replace the text in the line with an empty string.
The easiest way is to include the line break in your search array:

```
$old = array("My Name", "To: storm@yahoo.com\n");
```